# How to access nested array properties with strongly typed query builders in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Trying to figure out how to access nested array properties when using the strongly typed query builders for mongodb in c#.  Lets say I have the following classes:

```
public class V {
    public Guid _id { get; set; }
    public List<S> S { get; set; }
}

public class S {
    public Guid I { get; set;}
    /* other fields */
}
```

V is the document type.  I want to build a query like this:

```
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
var query = Query<V>.EQ(v => v.S.I, id);
```

However that doesn't compile because the S property on V is a List.  The resulting mongo query that I would look like to see is this (actual guid syntax is not correct, but the left side is the important part:

```
{ "S.I": "99ebc751-c12a-4873-8c3f-cb510b26a082" }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: var query = Query.EQ("S.I", id); ?

Comment: I'm trying to do it without strings, using the strongly typed builders

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do it as Nuk Nuk mentioned in a comment to your question. Alternatively, you can use ElemMatch (docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch) which is possibly more appropriate anyways.

If you have a suggestion on how we could support this using typed syntax, please give some feedback.  For the same reason, we are struggling with how to support the positional ($) update operator.

Comment: I had written my own set of helper methods before I knew about this that took an expression and gave you back the string property representation of it.  But I was trying to switch to the more official version, since I figured it would support more of the custom mapping options.  In my implementation I created two extension methods for my scenario and the positional operator.  I just look for those extensions when I parse the expression.  I considered triggering off FirstOrDefault or similar methods, but I thought that might not be very intuitive.  I can send you my helpers if you want.

Comment: I'd love to know what the names of the methods are?  That is really our only issue.  We have debated on Member(), Element(), etc...

Comment: AnyItem and MatchedItem(for $)

Comment: Actually after thinking about, I think you should look for projection, since that is essentially what it is.  Example: v => v.S.Select(s => s.I.J.K), would turn into "S.I.J.K".  You would still need something for the positional update operator I think, since there's nothing that really corresponds in the language.

Comment: @CraigWilson - +1 on the name "Member". Although down the line I can see folks wanting to access a function on a type too.